# Convergence issues with GLMM from lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, convergence

I am new to mixed models and am having some trouble getting my models to converge. I've looked at the other questions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere and worked through [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html) sheet, but with no luck.

I have several variables derived from sweep net transects and pitfall traps, such as abundance, diversity and biomass. The experimental set up was 15 plots, split equally between three treatments, with each plot being surveyed 7 times for a total sample size of 105. Here I will use the total abundance of invertebrates found in each sweep net survey as an example. This is basically count data, with a Poisson distribution, lots of zeros, and a few higher values:

[image]

I can't log transform my data because of the zeros, and this led me down the route of doing a Poisson `GLMM` from the `lme4` package instead.  The formula I'm using is:

```
ab.sw <- glmer(Sweep.abund ~ Treatment * (as.factor(Set)) + (1|Plot),
               data = Data, family = poisson)
```

Set is a 'survey set': one survey of every plot in our study.  Its a factor because surveys are not equally spaced throughout the study period and we don't want surveys at the end of the study period having a disproportionate influence on our models. This code gets me this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00381319 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I can't rescale my variables because they're all factors. Increasing the number of iterations produced the same (or very similar) error. I don't think my fit is singular:

```
tt <- getME(ab.sw,"theta")
ll <- getME(ab.sw,"lower")
min(tt[ll==0])
[1] 0.3788906
```

I've also tried using different optimizers with `optimx` and `all_fit`. Here are the results from `all_fit`:

```
aa <- all_fit(ab.sw)

bobyqa. : [OK]
Nelder_Mead. : [OK]
optimx.nlminb : [OK]
optimx.L-BFGS-B : [OK]
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD : [ERROR]
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA : [ERROR]
nmkbw. : [ERROR]

is.OK <- sapply(aa,is,"merMod")
aa.OK <- aa[is.OK]
lapply(aa.OK,function(x) x@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages)

$bobyqa.
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues"

$Nelder_Mead.
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues"

$optimx.nlminb
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 6 negative eigenvalues"

$`optimx.L-BFGS-B`
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 6 negative eigenvalues"
```

My gradient calculations are above the 0.001 threshold and this seems to be what the first warning in my error message is about:

```
derivs1 <- ab.sw@optinfo$derivs
sc_grad1 <- with(derivs1,solve(Hessian,gradient))
max(abs(sc_grad1))
[1] 0.003052968
```

What is it about my data which is preventing my models from working and is there anything I can do to fix it? Failing that is there any other modelling approach which might work for my data?

I'm using R version 3.4.3 with `lme4` version 1.1-13.

Comment: This seems like a "stats" question; you might try Cross Validated.  Is one of your groups entirely 0?  If so, you will need to think about what to do with that group.  Regardless, given the long right tail and the enormous number of 0 values, it is extremely unlikely that the Poisson will fit these data (see the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#/media/File:Poisson_pmf.svg) for example distributions).  You could consider the negative binomial (`glmer.nb` or via package glmmTMB) or think about zero-inflated models.

Comment: You could plot the results based on various optimizers. If the results are consistent across optimizers, they would be more trustworthy. A function and a code-through is available at: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2021/a-new-function-to-plot-convergence-diagnostics-from-lme4-allfit/